# Android Material UI not able to change the background

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently upgraded my Gradle version to version 6.5 and now I get a new format.
values.xml is replaced with 2 `themes.xml`. When I go to `activity_main.xml`, I can't change the background colour of a button.
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="195dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In design view it looks like this:

[image]

I upgraded my android studio to version 4.1 and it changed the Gradle version.
When I downgrade my Gradle version it doesn't allow it to.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `android:backgroundTint` for API Level 21 and higher, or `app:backgroundTint` for API Level 7 and higher.